# AWS ECS Fargate Task cannot pull secrets from SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm bootstrapping an ECS Cluster with AWS CDK.
I created SecureStrings in SSM which I want to pass to the container secrets.

But when starting the service I get the following error message on the task:

```
"ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve secrets from ssm: service call has been retried 1 time(s): AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::<ACCOUNT_ID>:assumed-role..."
```

The task runs in a private VPC, so I attached a VPC endpoint for service name com.amazonaws.eu-central-1.ssm to the VPC (both subnets). I also created a security group that allows TCP 443 INBOUND from 0.0.0.0/0 and attached that security group to the VPC endpoint.

I have no clue what I should do for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact you are getting an access denied may mean you don't have the proper permissions specified in the Task role. Check out the considerations listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-parameters.html).

Comment: Yes, I was referencing the wrong task execution role in my code -.-

Comment: This is also the error you receive when referencing a non-existing ssm parameter.